# Ubuntu via vagrant with GUI

Tags: vagrant

I need to create virtual machine with some installed packages. This virtual machine shoud provide GUI. I tried to do it like described [there](https://github.com/zyga/vagrant-desktop-images).

But achieve strange result. I see plain console window in virtualbox application when it opens.

My vagragantfile is simple:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

      # Use a basic trusty desktop image from git://github.com/zyga/vagrant-destop-images.git
      config.vm.box = "trusty-desktop-i386"
      # TODO: offer premade images for download
      config.vm.box_url = ""

      # Tweak VirtualBox configuration for GUI applications
      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.gui = true
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", 64]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--accelerate3d", "on"]
      end

      # Automatically use local apt-cacher-ng if available
      if File.exists? "/etc/apt-cacher-ng"
        # If apt-cacher-ng is installed on this machine then just use it.
        require 'socket'
        guessed_address = Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| !intf.ipv4_loopback?}
        if guessed_address
          config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Acquire::http { Proxy \"http://#{guessed_address.ip_address}:3142\"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00proxy"
        end
      end

      # Update to have the latest packages, remove if you don't need that
      config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update"
      config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade --yes"

      # Ready :-)
end
```

Can somebody provide a working example of using vagrant with UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to install a desktop environment, such as [xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) or alike
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878117/using-vagrant-to-run-virtual-machines-with-desktop-environment) explains more or less how to do it.

Comment: You missed a link to the post