# How do I install a Vagrant Linux box that has a GUI (gnome, kde, ...)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant

How do I install a Vagrant Linux box that has a Desktop GUI (gnome, kde, ...).

Is there a Vagrant box distribution that already has a Desktop environment?

After I do a "vagrant up" how do I log into this virtual box and with the GUI active?

Comment: I use the GUI on the host machine to work (edit and handle version control) on the guest VM through the share/sync drive.  The VM runs the site/application.   You can add vm.gui=true to use the VirtualBox GUI, or you can just vagrant ssh in.

Answer (score 13):

This question is a duplicate with an extensive answer here: [Using vagrant to run virtual machines with desktop environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878117/using-vagrant-to-run-virtual-machines-with-desktop-environment)

Yes, you need to enable the GUI in your vagrant file, but first you need to:

- Install Virtual Box Guest additions
- Install your desktop environment

From one of the answer in the link above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33138627/1412348), you can use the following vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # Ubuntu 15.10
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/wily64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true
  end

  # Install xfce and virtualbox additions
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get update"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get install -y xfce4 virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11"
  # Permit anyone to start the GUI
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo sed -i 's/allowed_users=.*$/allowed_users=anybody/' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config"
end
```

Comment: This worked for me. To get desktop to start - login to virtualbox instance and type "startx"

Comment: when I tried this, I got a 404 error for wily64

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. 
The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

when I tried to use this in its place
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

I got an x11 error.
    default: Running: inline script
    default: sed: can't read /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config: No such file or directory

Answer (score 5):

If you want to enter the Desktop GUI, you can modify the Vagrantfile to add `vb.gui = true`. For example:

> ```
> config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
>     # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
>     vb.gui = true
>
>     # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
>     # vb.memory = "1024"
> end
> ```

Then you can `vagrant up` and enter it from virtualbox.

Comment: Please show me your full Vagrantfile that does this.  If I am using ubuntu 64 bit then I do NOT have to add any GUI system files?  That is, VirtualBox will be the GUI separate from the ubuntu?

Comment: e, I thought you just want to enter it through virtualbox, if you want it to show the desktop, the ubuntu must install the desktop using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`